# Python pandas plot: Using two columns to generate one y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns: condition, trial and time. I would like to visualize a scatter plot where the x-axis represents the time column and the y-axis represents the condition. The special part is that each condition has n trials. So in the dataframe there are n rows with the same condition marked with different trial indices (1-n) in the trial column. In the plot I would like to display each trial in a separate row (y-position), i.e. that each condition on the y-axis should be subdivided into n trials.

Currently, I plot the dataframe as follows:  `df.plot(x = 'Time', y = 'Condition', kind = 'scatter', s = 1)`

However, this plots all trials for each condition on the same horizontal line. Do you have any suggestions how to split each condition on the y-axis into the separate trials? I would be very grateful!

Greetings and thanks, sonicycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal solution will depend on how many trials and conditions you have. If there are not too many, you could use seaborn's [`catplot()`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) function, which is designed to split such categorical data into several suitably aligned subplots. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Condition': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
                   'Trial': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                   'Time': [0.7, 3.4, 2.1, 3.5, 6.3, 7.4]})

sns.catplot(x='Time', y='Trial', row='Condition', hue='Condition',
            data=df, kind='strip', s=10, height=2, aspect=4);
```

[image: two aligned stripplots]

Comment: Thank you very much for this idea! I have 15 conditions and 11 trials, so the computation really took a while (some hours), but that was no problem for me.

Thanks and Greetings
sonicycle